# Rails SVG: Unsafe attempt to load URL from frame

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, svg, asset-pipeline

In rails 4.2.4, I am using `<svg>` for loading some icons. Right now icons are loading in localhost with no errors but in other environment icons are loading with an error like

```
Unsafe attempt to load URL https://d188zm8yub6iju.cloudfront.net/assets/svg/symbol-defs-f5e098511deb471448ee9708bb35cc8914b3e430762c63265744db5f8e9fbcae.svg from frame with URL http://test.yesdoc.com/. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

Also I have tried to fix it by referring this https://github.com/jonathantneal/svg4everybody but it is not working.

In views,

```
<svg role="img" title="Post" class="svg-post hidden-sx">
   <use xlink:href="<%= asset_path("svg/symbol-defs.svg#svg-post") %>"></use>
</svg>

<script type="text/javascript">
  svg4everybody();
</script>
```

And file path is `/app/assets/images/svg/symbol-defs.svg`

How can I fix this error by using `svg4everybody()` or without using it?

Comment: Did you read [this](https://github.com/jonathantneal/svg4everybody/issues/16)? "Without setting up your CDN to allow requests, this is a security feature (and in your case limitation) of cross domain requests, and not of SVGs or this library per say."

Comment: Yes. I have checked CDN configuration and other things, but same issue is there.